# Assigning a number to a text block

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8

I want to set the **Text** of a **TextBlock** according to the Value of a Random Number

I thought about using `toString` for getting the **String** of the Random number
and then assigning it to the **TextBlock**

My Code:

```
 Random Rnd = new Random();
            Number1 = Rnd.Next(1, 12);
            Number2 = Rnd.Next(1, 12);
            num1.Text = Number1.ToString;
        num2.Text = Number2.ToString;
```

When I run the code
and  it gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'.
>   Did you intend to invoke the method?

But both side's types are String , why can't I assign it ?

Comment: "But both side's types are String". No they are not

Comment: You wouldn't get that error from that code - you don't mention `ToString` anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not calling the `ToString` method. In this statement:

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString;
```

... `ToString` is a *method group*, which can be used for conversions to delegate types. So for example, this *is* valid:

```
Func<string> stringProvider = Number1.ToString;
```

That's why the error message talks about method groups.

For a method *invocation*, however, you definitely need the brackets. This is a difference between C# and VB. (In VB, you'd need `AddressOf` to create a delegate for a method group, but *don't* need to specify the brackets when invoking a parameterless method.)

You need:

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString();
num2.Text = Number2.ToString();
```

(Additionally, I strongly suggest you follow normal C# naming conventions, where non-constant variables are camelCased rather than PascalCased, but that's a slightly different matter.)

Comment: Unless I'm misreading what you've put, `num2.Text = Number2.ToString;` would not be valid in VB.NET, `;` is not used to terminate a statement, it would say `Unexpected token`

Comment: @DarrenDavies: Sorry, I mis-stated that. I meant that the "ToString without brackets" bit would be valid. Have edited.

Comment: @JonSkeet but that's what i did , still gives me an error

Comment: @GabourX: "still gives me an error" doesn't give us *nearly* enough information. The same error? A different error? Where are `Number1` and `Number2` declared? It doesn't help that your original question didn't even show the real code giving the error you described... it's important to take time when asking a question (or adding comments) to give relevant and accurate information. In particular, a short but complete example program would have made it *much* easier to help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Not the same error , the error is :  **Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?**

Comment: @GabourX: That's the exact same error that you showed in your question. So when you say "Not the same error" what do you mean?

Comment: @JonSkeet am sorry , because i did not write the Updated code , the previous error was : **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'** when i Forgot to add `.toString` to the Number1 and Number2

Comment: @GabourX: Okay, so the code I've given fixes both of those errors. Just using `num1.Text = Number1.ToString()` should be fine. (It's worth looking back on this question and trying to understand how confusing it's been for people trying to help you. Please learn from this.)

Answer (score 4):

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString;
num2.Text = Number2.ToString;
```

Isn't valid c# syntax.

You could use:

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString();
num2.Text = Number2.ToString();
```

Or

```
num1.Text = Convert.ToString(Number1);
num2.Text = Convert.ToString(Number2);
```

Where `Convert.ToString` handles `null` values and `value.ToString()` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Try this as `.Next()` returns an `int`

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString();
num2.Text = Number2.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert Number1 and Number2 to string like

```
num1.Text = Number1.ToString();
num2.Text = Number2.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert Number1 and Number2 to string before assigning it to a text box like

```
  num1.Text=Number1.ToString();
  num2.Text=Number2.ToString();
```

Comment: You are right about that and to emphasize your funny typo: I know it 'stings' :)